# How to retain Fragment state For orientation change of device?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I got error on change of orientation of Actionbar Tab fragment. I read post regarding  state management in android.

I got solution that use `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

But in my case `onTabUnselected` event I got error for fragment object

```
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {      
    System.out.println("1::");
    Fragment fragment = adapter.getItem(tab.getPosition());
    System.out.println("2::"+fragment);<--- shows long id
    **line 112 -->if (fragment instanceof InfoFragment) {   <--- error at this line Null** pointer excp     
        ((InfoFragment) fragment).setData();
    }else if (fragment instanceof PortFragment) {           
        ((PortFragment) fragment).setData();                
    }
}
```

> [image]

How to resolve it by calling `onSaveInstanceState`?

```
// Set data to objects
public void setData() {
    List<String> sales = new ArrayList<String>();

    sales.add(0, String.valueOf(customerId));       
    sales.add(1, String.valueOf(prospectId));       
    sales.add(2, String.valueOf(commodityId));
    sales.add(3, txtAESplNt.getText().toString());
    sales.add(4, Constants.Common.AIR_LOB);

    //set data to global class
    mainActivity.setSalesInfoData(sales);
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have added the `InfoFragment` in backstack.

Comment: no i havent how to use it ?

Comment: Which data you are trying to set ?

Comment: @GrIsHu please see code above edited